# how to over ride glyph icon color different from parent class?

Tags: css, stylesheet

Im trying to over ride Glyph icon color for one of my icons in mobile layout, i want to change the colour of single icon but im unable to change color, when i change color from stylesheet, all of the icons color gets changed, i just want to change only 1 icon color to something different then others. 
this is my code:

[This is My glyph icon which i want to change color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr3CP.png)

[This is the Style Sheet code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4TaF.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you post the rule on the parent as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #dg-left .menu-left li a i::before {
       color:#333333 !important;
      }
```

The important modifier overrides the parent class css.

Comment: Probably better to increase the specificity and save `!important` for a last resort.

Comment: you did not understand
 
   #dg-left .menu-left li a i::before {
       color:#333333
      }

is already working fine without !important its just that when i change the color from 

    #dg-left .menu-left li a i::before {
       color:#333333
      }

all icons color get changed, i just want to change 1 icon color not all icon color